# PHP Multiple foreach

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, foreach, while-loop

I am trying to insert data from an array in mysql. I have multiple arrays. I have been trying to do something along the lines of this.

```
foreach ($titles as $title && $descriptions as $description) {
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO `stock` VALUES('', '$title', '$description')");
}
```

I would like mysql table to look like this.

```
item_id    title    description
_______________________________

1          title1   description1
2          title2   description2
...
```

Now I have figured out this won't work is there any alternative to this. I have seen examples of while loops to do this but i am struggling to understand how that would work.
All help is appreciated in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if size of `$titles` equal size of `$descriptions` and, you have sequencial arrays, you can do:

```
<?php
$titles = array(
    'foo',
    'bar'
);
$descriptions = array(
    'foo description',
    'bar description'
);

for($i = 0; $i < count($titles); $i++) {
    $title = $titles[$i];
    $description = $descriptions[$i];

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO `stock` VALUES('', '$title', '$description')");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for a [`MultipleIterator`](http://php.net/multipleiterator), which will iterate over both arrays easily:

```
$iter = new MultipleIterator;
$iter->attachIterator( new ArrayIterator( $titles));
$iter->attachIterator( new ArrayIterator( $descriptions));

foreach( $iter as $data) {
    list( $title, $description) = $data;
    // Do your SQL insert with $title and $description
}
```